# start linux installation from a linux

Tags: linux, installation, pxe-boot, automated-install

Need to network install ubuntu/centos after preparing RAID/BIOS/Firmware.

Right now, a machine first boots into a tiny linux kernel(resides in memory) and run scripts handling all the above hardware things, then boots from network again and start installing centos/ubuntu. I wonder if there is a way to avoid rebooting and start linux installing right in the tiny linux kernel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

What I use for network installations, from a hypervisor, of ubuntu is: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/

This is where you can find several installation options, and probably also one that fits your needs.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: I setup my own distribution http mirror locally, and this is not my problem. But thanks anyway.